# How to identify this shower faucet or cartridge brand to stop tub spout leak and remove screw-less escutcheon plate?

Tags: repair, shower, leak, faucet, cartridge

I’m working on a bathroom and trying to fix a slow leak coming out of the tub spout.  Since it’s from the spout I’m assuming the leak is generating from the cartridge or the associated o-rings/seats & Springs.  I

**Does anyone recognize the brand of crystal faucet handle in the picture?**

It’s a simple handle that you twist to turn the water on/off - does not go up/down.  I was able to take off the handle (picture 2) and expose the top of the shower cartridge but for some reason was not able to pry off the escutcheon even after loosening the caulk. There are no screws on the plate and it seems like it was fastened onto something behind the wall and I didn’t want to force it. **Could the escutcheon screwed/fastened in a different way for disassembly?**

[image: Shower Faucet Handle]
[image: Shower Faucet Cartridge Tip]

Comment: does the center ring screw off? are you positive there isnt a single screw underneath you are missing? Those are two common methods. Looks like a moen color/design

Comment: looks like there is a thread in the bottom picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to finally get the water shutoff a couple days back (apt. complex) and turned out to be a Price Pfister!